# work-flow for multi-tasking - Mac(Applescript) ¿is possible?

Tags: applescript

I am a computer science student at a university and my workflow usually has many open windows and I would like to know if in Mac in addition to the multi desktop horizontal scrolling it is possible to do a kind of vertical scroling between windows of the same desktop so that the change of windows either by a gesture either of the keyboard or of the trackpad that allows changing from one window to another of those that are on the current desktop as if it were a "circular" queue.

https://github.com/diegoalfarog/WindowQueueMac

Comment: If you have a trackpad you can do an up gesture with three fingers to show all open windows on the current desktop and switch like that. I don't think that Applescript is the right tab for this and I would ask similar questions related to MacOS on https://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thanks, i know about mission control gestures, but I want if I do the same gesture, it will switch between windows like a circular queue without choosing between them. About Applecript, I don't know so much that I just asked with that tag to reach out to people with knowledge on mac

Comment: I don't know how to do the circular queue thing, but I would recommend you asking the same on https://apple.stackexchange.com.